# WebDAV: Mini-Redirector client - got own (read-only?) cookie-storage?

Tags: webdav

Imagine this szenario: Web-Server and WebDAV-Server using same cookie-domain.
WebServer sets some authentication cookie.

When starting an WebDAV-Session via special-link on the Web-Server,
WIN7 Microsoft Mini-redirector can read the cookie
set by Web-Server fine and starts an WebDAV-Session 
on WebDAV-server using this cookie.

But after the first DAV-call, the cookie seems to be read-only
to both DAV-Server and mini-redirector.

1. DAV-Server cannot update this cookie
2. DAV-Server cannot delete (expiry in the past) the cookie
3. Mini-redirector keeps sending the old values
   (even, if Web-Server has updated its values in between)

Anybody got informations

1. where mini-redirector stores its cookies
2. how to avoid this behaviour?

Thanks, Karl

Comment: Not a true answer.. but.. would you need a cookie? Sounds like a bad idea to try to maintain state that way. HTTP should be stateless, and haven't seen many WebDAV clients that support cookies.

Comment: @Evert: Actually Miniredirector supports cookies with one exception: OPTIONS request will be sent without cookies. This exception makes cookies useless with Miniredirector as your session will be reset during OPTIONS request.

Comment: @user695797: Ah k :) We'll I've been a maintainer of a semi-popular WebDAV server; and I would discourage _anyone_ to use cookies. It seems very unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. On the client you should know when the server is updating the cookie. When you know server may reset the cookie, call wnetcancelconnection2 and clear of the the existing webdav connection and call wnetaddconnection2 to create the connection again. But give some time between these two calls atleast a minute, i guess it takes a while to clean up the existing cache.

In my application when i knew the server is going down or my application exiting or going to ask for new session, i call the wnetcancelconnection2 and wnetaddconnection2. It worked for me. Hope this helps.